# How to fix LIBEAY32.dll issue?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, dll, dreamweaver

Apparently Mozy installs a version of LIBEAY32.dll that is incompatible with Dreamweaver - http://community.mozy.com/t5/Mozy-for-Windows/Mozy-kills-Adobe-Dreamweaver/td-p/38521 . This causes Dreamweaver to not work properly.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to install the proper versions and make sure that each software uses the correct one?

Working in Windows XP SP3.

EDIT: Update: If I suspend Mozy, then Dreamweaver starts fine. Is it possible that they are sharing the same DLL that is loaded into memory? Is there a way to force one or the other to not "share" the DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incompatibility introduced in Mozy. I uninstalled it and installed version 2.10, which works fine. Then turned off auto update in options.

There is a thread on this in the Mozy forums, so I hope they fix it in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

If `Dreamweaver.exe` and `libeay32.dll` are in the same folder, try creating an empty file named `Dreamweaver.exe.local` next to them; it should force the local libraries to be used first.

Comment: They are in the same folder, and I created the file, but I still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Mozy and Dreamweaver to work side by side by copying the `libeay32.dll` and and `ssleay32.dll` from the `C:\Program Files\Mozy` directory over the ones in the Dreamweaver directory (be sure to make copies of those DLL's before overwriting them). Mozy is running with the OpenSSL version 1.0.0e which appears to be newer than the one built and signed by Adobe.